# How can I follow an _id in Mongoose.js to find an item and process it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to databases and these MongoDB/Mongoose.js async functions have annoyed the hell out of me over the last few hours. I have written and rewritten this bit so many times:

```
router.get('/districts', function(req, res) {
  districtNames = [];

  // I'm using mongoose-simpledb, so db.District refers to the districts collection
  db.District.find(function(err, found) {    
    found.forEach(function(element) {
      findParentProv(element, districtNames);
    });

    res.render('districts', {title: "Districts page", district_list: districtNames});
  })
});

function findParentProv(element, namesArray) {
  db.Province.findById(element.parent, function(err, found) {
    console.log(found.name);
    namesArray.push(element.name + " " + found.name);
  });
}
```

I want to get all items in the `districts` collection, follow their `parent` field (which contains an ObjectID), find that item from the `provinces` collection and push both their names as a string into `districtNames`.

How should I do this?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the `populate` feature? http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: @BatScream Looks promising, but I don't understand it. How can I use that here?

Comment: You just do `db.District.find(...).populate('parent').exec(function(err, found) {...})`, and then you should be able to access `element.parent.name`. This just requires setting `parent` as a reference in the district schema (i.e. `parent : { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Province' }`).

Answer (score 0):

Best bet moving forward is to use [ES6 Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) patterns to help with your callback patterns..
suggested modules:

- `lodash` [optional] has a lot of useful methods, not needed here, but you may need, for example _.flatten, or _.assign
- `i-promise` will give you a native Promise (node 0.11.3+) or a scripted implementation
- `es6-promise` is the fallback for `i-promise` to use
- `promisify-patch` is an inline promisify for specific methods.

Install the modules required for your use (in this example).

```
npm install --save es6-promise i-promise promisify-patch
```

Use Promise pattern with your example.

```
require('promisify-patch').patch();
var Promise = require('i-promise')
    ;

//returns a promise to resolve to your list for display
function getDistricts() {
  //gets all of the db.District
  return db.District.find.bind(db.District).promise() 
    //after districts retrieved
    .then(function(districts){ 
      //resolve an array of promises, will return an array of results
      return Promise.all(districts.map(getDistrictProv)); //map each district via getDistrictProv
    });
}

//returns a promise to resolve a specific district/province name
function getDistrictProv(district){
  return db.Provice.findById.bind(db.Province).promise(element.parent)
    .then(function(province){
      return district.name + ' ' + province.name;
    });
}

...

//express handler
router.get('/districts', function(req, res, next) {
  //get the district names
  getDistricts()
    //then process the rendering with the names
    .then(function(names){
      res.render('districts', {title: "Districts page", district_list: names});
    })
    //if there was an error in the promise chain
    // pass it along, so it can be handled by another express plugin
    .catch(next)
});
```

---

Disclosure: I made `i-promise` and `promisify-patch` to make situations like this easier to convert node-style callbacks into promise chains.

---

NOTE: If you are creating general purpose libraries for Node or the Browser that are not flow-control related, you should at least implement the node-style callback implementation.

Further, you may wish to look into `co`, `koa` for using generators as well.

---

The question seemed to be how to control the flow of data, in which promises are likely the best answer.  If your issue is trying to fit non-relational data into a relational box or vice-versa, may want to re-evaluate your data structure as well...

http://blog.mongodb.org/post/88473035333/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3

You should probably have some key data for parents/children replicated to those affected documents in other collections.  There are configuration options via Mongoose to support this, but that doesn't mean you should avoid the consideration.

If you do many/large join operations like this it will negatively affect your performance.  This isn't meant to be a religious comment only that MongoDB/SQL or other SQL vs. NoSQL considerations should be made depending on your actual needs.

The data in question seems to be highly cacheable data that may well be better with a relational/sql database.

Comment: Wow. That much work just to retrieve the name field in a document that I already have the id for? Is there no better way to rethink all of this?

Comment: Yeah... put the `provinceName` in your `District` collection... then have an event hook to update `District` when a given `Province` updates.  That's how you *SHOULD* do it anyway... you should be denormalizing your data.

Comment: @Tomty exactly... Unless this is being deployed on a replica-set to begin with, it's probably highly cacheable data that may well be better suited to an RDBMS ... Document stores aren't really meant for doing JOIN operations, you're supposed to replicate frequently needed data, and make sure that data is properly updated.

It's better for mostly-read situations, and can work very well.  It's not a replacement for SQL databases (and their own replication), though MongoDB replica sets are far easier to setup than most DBs.  If you have a DBA on staff, use an SQL db for this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you do seem to be on the right track.

The one major issue I recognize in your solution is that after kicking off all the async queries for parents, you immediately return the (most likely empty) districtNames array, without waiting for the queries to finish.

This is indeed very annoying, and not surprisingly so. MongoDB is a non-relational DB, and so join operations like what you're trying to do aren't easy to get right.

The solution that would probably require the least fundamental changes to what you're doing would be to wait on all the queries before calling `res.render`. The most basic way to do this would be to check the length of namesArray/districtNames after pushing each element, and once you see it's gotten to the desired size, only then calling `render`. There are, however, more standardized ways of doing this, and I'd suggest looking into something like [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async) (specifically async.parallel) or a Promise framework such as [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird).

Now, another approach to solving this problem is de-normalizing the data. For someone with a relational background this probably sound appalling, but in Mongo it might actually be a valid solution to just include the province names along with their IDs in the districts collection, in which case your one initial query should be sufficient.

Another approach, which might be suitable if you're dealing with relatively small collections, would be to run 2 queries, 1 for all the districts and 1 for all the provinces, and do the correlation in-app. Obviously, this isn't a very efficient solution, and should definitely be avoided if there's any chance the collections contain, or will in the future contain, more than a handful of objects.